# Have somebody doing something

Tags: causative-have, resultative

I want to express at the beginning of the lesson that I hope that all my listeners will enjoy my speech. Can I use the causative structure?
*I hope I will have you enjoying this lecture.*

And what about this sentence: *I hope I will have you enjoy the lesson.*

What is the difference between *have somebody doing something* and *have somebody do something*? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The causative structure is really for when you have paid/asked for something to be done, e.g. the gardening.

> I had those horrible weeds dug up.

The above example shows the form *have + object + past participle*.

In the case you describe, you cannot **make** the listeners enjoy the speech, so you can't use the causative form above. You can of course be the cause of their happiness/enjoyment if your speech is good, which is why we have to say more directly:

> I hope you will enjoy this lesson/lecture.

So if you can't say enjoy, what *can* you say? Well, since it must be something that you can *make happen*, let's try "laugh":

> I hope I will have you laughing by the end of this talk.

This verb can be used, since it is you who is directly provoking the reaction (of laughing).

So *have + somebody + verb + -ing* is the structure we can use for a result that *you* create:

> [I had them eating out of the palm of my hand](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+eating+out+of+the+palm+of+hand).

*Have + somebody + infinitive* is the structure used when we want to talk about the person who did something that we paid/asked them to do:

> I had the gardener dig up those horrible weeds.